# Is it safe to access an object X within a synchronized block defined on object Y?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized, volatile

There are answers to the question if accessing the state of the object is safe within the synchronized method or block. My question : Is it safe to access an object X within a synchronized block, where synchronized block is on another object Y and  there are multiple writers Threads present for X ?

```
public class X{
    private int value = 0;
    /** set method will be invoked by multiple threads**/
    public void set(int v){
       this.value = v;
   }
   public int value(){
       return value;
   }
}

public class Tester{
    private final Object Y = new Object();
    public void test(X x){
        synchronized(Y){
            System.out.println(x.value()); // is it guaranteed that x.value will be read from memory and not from the current thread's cache ?
        }
    }
}
```

I know state of the object on which synchronized block is defined is safe to access without a need for volatile, but what if the synchronized block is defined on another object ?

Comment: All invocations of set and value need to be mutually synchronized in order for a value call to see the set value.

Comment: It's safe as long as everybvody has the same instance of `Y`  and synchronizes on it. Rather simpler to synchronize on the `X` itself, don't you think?

Comment: @AndyTurner yes Got it, thanks for the answer, I don't know how I got confused to this extent. Shall I delete the question as this answers it, the comment itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMO you are asking the wrong question. The Java Memory Model doesn't concern itself with objects and classes. It only talks about the visibility of *variables*.

The visibility rule for `synchronized(o)` blocks is pretty simple: Whatever one thread does to any variable before it leaves a `synchronized(o)` block is guaranteed to be visible to any other thread after the other thread subsequently enters a block that is `synchronized` on the same instance, `o`.

So, in your example, if you have some `X my_x`, and some thread A does this:

```
synchronized(Y) {
    my_x.set(55);
}
```

Then when some other thread B subsequently calls `tester.test(my_x)`, thread B will see the value that was stored by thread A.

On the other hand, if thread A calls `my_x.set(...)` *without* synchronizing on `Y`, then Java does not promise when, if ever, the thread B will see the change.

---

Note: Your program openly invites failure by making the lock object, `Y`, a `private` member of the `Tester` class, while making the `test(X)` function `public`. That practically begs you (or some other programmer) to make the mistake of calling `tester.test(some_random_X)` where the `some_random_X` was set by another thread that did *not* lock `Y`.

Answer (score -3):

No it is not safe.

Unrelated to the question:

First problem with the example code:

```
public void set(int v){
    this.value = v;
}
```

this is extremely poor code quality and should really be written like this:

```
public final void setValue(final int value) {
    this.value = value;
}
```

this has no performance benefit other than addition of the final modifiers may improve bytecode optimization it is just a design pattern for setters.

Second problem with the example code:

```
public int value(){
    return value;
}
```

the correct design pattern for a getter is:

```
public final int getValue() {
    return value;
}
```

Third problem with the example code:

```
private final Object Y = new Object();
```

the field 'Y' is not static and therefore is not a constant, the correct naming convention for this field would be:

```
private final Object y = new Object();
```

The forth problem with the example code is the putting braces after parentheses without a space, what i mean by that is instead of doing

```
){
```

you should really be doing:

```
) {
```

Comment: thanks for the inputs, I presented the code sample to put forward the question and focus on the synchronization, your inputs are an eye opener that when ever and how so ever you present a code sample, better keep it well formatted with all the conventions in place. Thanks buddy. +1

Comment: just add the comment from Andy (mention his name) : All invocations of set and value need to be mutually synchronized in order for a value call to see the set value.

This answers the question and then you can have your answer follow it, I all accept it as it answers my question.

Comment: *extremely poor code quality* I'm generally in favor of making things final in general, but property accessors are almost always non-final, and such broad statements are unjustified. Additionally, minor issues like code spacing have nothing to do with the essence of the question, which is about synchronization and *happens-before*.

Comment: If any method, property accessor or not is not overridden it should be final, my reasoning for this is readability.

Comment: `final` adds almost no value when you use it on arguments and locals. If the function is not too large, then anybody reading it can plainly see whether the variable is assigned or not; and if the function _is_ too large, then it's too large—it should be broken up. In either case, a modern compiler can always tell whether or not there are any assignments to it, so adding `final` will have no effect on the code that the compiler emits.

Comment: Re, "the field 'Y' is not static and therefore is not a constant." That's not what `static` means.

Comment: RE: For something to be a constant it has to be static and final, the field in question "Y" is final and if static were to be added it would become a constant. final does add value especially to local variables and parameters (which are local variables in bytecode) as it allows the compiler to apply simply optimizations.

Comment: Constants do not have to be `static`. It’s debatable whether a variable of type `Object` can ever be a constant at all. A *compile-time constant* must have a primitive type or type `String`, but does *not* require a variable to be `static`. `final String s = "foo";` is a compile-time constant, regardless of context. Even when it is a local variable. In contrast, `final String s; s = "foo";` does not define a compile-time constant and when it is a local variable, there is no effect at all. The fact that a local variable has been declared `final` does not even appear in the compiled code.

Comment: I'm not referring literally to it being a constant I'm referring to the design pattern in which case it would be `static final int VALUE = 2;`, and I was referring to when the code is being compiled it results in more optimized code not that it is literally better to have it or that there is a bytecode instruction for it.